# Problems with date time and infinite loops

Tags: c#

I know there probably is a really an obvious answer to this question but why am I  getting an infinite loop with this code?
(laterDate1 is later date than dateTime1 and laterDate2 is a later date than dateTime2)

```
while (dateTime1.CompareTo(laterDate1) <= 0)
        {
            DateTime dateTime2 = otherDateTime;
            while (dateTime2.CompareTo(laterDate2) <= 0)
            {
                dateTime2.AddDays(1);
            }
            dateTime1.AddDays(1);
        }
```

Thanks in advance for your help. (My brain is not working today)

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that `DateTime` overloads the comparison operators, like [`operator <=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_lessthanorequal.aspx), so you can say `while (dateTime1 <= laterDate1)` directly which is easier to read.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you actually trying to do? Specifically what is the purpose of the nested loops? The inner loop doesn't appear to have any reference to the outer one.

Comment: The original code was a little more complicates, I removed some of it. The code was used to check if there was enough room in a hotel on any particular day that the new customer wants to stay there for.

Answer (score 7):

`dateTime1.AddDays(1);` does not modify `dateTime1`. It returns new `DateTime` instance. You have to assign it back to your variable:

```
dateTime1 = dateTime1.AddDays(1);
```

The same applies to `dateTime2.AddDays(2)`:

```
dateTime2 = dateTime2.AddDays(1);
```

btw, `DateTime` is a struct and is immutable, so every state-changing method returns new instance, instead of modifying the one you're calling it on. You should remember about that while working with `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it was immutable but I just didn't put 2 and 2 together.